# Promise.then is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I am writing auth for my react app and the function that fetches the token can be seen below

```
axios.post("mywebsite.com/api/token-auth", {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
    })
    .then((fulfilled) => {

        userData = fulfilled.data;
        AsyncStorage.setItem("userData ", JSON.stringify(userData))
        .then(
            () => {
                this.scaleAnimationDialog.dismiss();
                // Set timeout is added to makesure the animation closes properly before navigating.
                setTimeout(
                    () => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home", userData), 500
                );
            }
        )
        .catch(
            () => {
                alert("Something went wrong, please try again");
                this.scaleAnimationDialog.dismiss();
            }
        )

    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.scaleAnimationDialog.dismiss();
        alert("Authentication failed please try again");
    });
```

When I try to login with valid credentials, it redirects to Home Screen as expected but if I refresh the app, it again goes to the LoginScreen as the AsyncStorage doesn't have key 'userData',

When the app fires up, LoadingScreen is the first component to load and which decides what screen to load. I implemented this as per react-navigation documentation and the code is as follows

```
_bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userDataString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData');
    const userDataObject = JSON.parse(userDataString);

    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userDataString ? "Home":"AuthNavigator", userDataObject);
  };
```

What am I doing wrong here. I am new to using promises, Please keep the answer more descriptive.

I also tried async await with try/catch but in that case the code never went past await and the loading popup never goes off. Please point out if my code is wrong and also suggest the appropriate solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How are you checking for the key in AsyncStorage?
Do it before the component renders, using the lifecycle method componentWillMount.

Something like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userData')
        .then(userData => {
            this.setState({ userData });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // Handle error here (maybe fetch user?)
        })
}
```

Then, inside the render method render accordingly this.state.userData.

Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Hello filipe, I updated my answer with the code I use to check if the data exists in AsyncStorage. the getItem implementation code is taken from the react native documentation.

Comment: Hello Kireeti. Try using the then() approach.
`AsyncStorage.getItem('userData').then(userDataString => { this.props.navigation.navigate("Home") }).catch(err => {this.props.navigation.navigate("AuthNavigator")})`

Comment: I have no problem with the getItem. After some digging, I found out AsyncStorage is not resolving, also raised an issue here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20310, Do you have any idea why that happens?

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with it: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14101

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found out there is this issue with AsyncStorage for lot of other people, thanks to @Filipe for pointing to the right thread. After a lot of struggle I've decided to just use localstorage like sqlite or something and found this library https://github.com/sunnylqm/react-native-storage. It implements AsyncStorage internally and provides a wrapper to set and get data. Somehow this seems to work for me. If anyone is facing the same issue as me. Give that library a try.